# Showing data from multiple related tables

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Using Rails 2.3.8. I wanna show data from complicated relationship.

These are in my models:

**shop.rb**

```
has_many :city_shops

id | name 
3  | Good Cafe
```

**city_shop.rb**

```
belongs_to :city
belongs_to :shop

id | city_id | shop_id | notes
2  |    4    |    3    | Delicious food in Paris
```

**city.rb**

```
belongs_to :article
has_many :city_shops
has_many :shops, :through => :city_shops

id | article_id
4  |    5
```

**article.rb**

```
has_many :shops, :through => :shop_articles
has_many :cities, :dependent => :destroy

id | user_id | name
5  |    6    | Favorite shops in France
```

**user.rb**

```
has_many :articles

id | login
6  | victor
```

The scenario is this (may not be logical):
A user with ID 6 creates many articles. Let's say he creates this article called **Favorite shops in France**. In this article, there are `cities`. In each `city`, there are `city_shops` where in it there are details `shop` and `notes` from `city_shops`.

I also have individual `shop` page. I want the visitors to know what notes have been left by users, where the note is and the link to that user's article.

In the `shop` page, it should read:

**Notes by users**
"Delicious food in Paris" by "victor", shared in "link to favorite shops in France".

I hope this question is clearer than previous. Thank you very much.

Comment: So, you have @shop and want to display data from associated models ?

Comment: Reading this guide: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html should help you undertand associations.

Comment: I have revised my question and given more details. Can you look at it again? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Notes by users:<br />
<% @shop.city_shops.each do |city_shop| %>
  "<%= city_shop.notes %>" by "<%= city_shop.city.article.user.login%>", shared in <%= link_to city_shop.city.article.name, "#{url}" %><br />
<% end >
```

You have to provide the url in the link and you have to add this also to your Article model:

```
belongs_to :user
```

Comment: Value of <%= city_shop.city.article.user.login%> or any plain text after <%= city_shop.notes %> will be shown twice somehow. Any reason why?

Comment: hmm...I cant think of any reason..can you try `city_shop.inspect` to understand what is going on..

Answer (score 1):

```
<% @shop.city_shops.each do |city_shop| %>
   city_shops notes: <%= city_shop.notes %>
   users: <%= city_shop.city.country.user.username %>
   country_id: <%= city_shop.city.country_id %>
<% end %>
```

There is something strange with your models.

Comment: I have given more details on the question. I hope it's clearer now. Can you please read through again? Thank you so much!